# Red Black Tree Rotation lost values when rotating

Tags: java, c#, data-structures, red-black-tree

I am having problems when performing a rotation on the tree. Without rotation insertion is good however, information is lost when rotation is performed.

Example inserting 50,75,40,45,25,45,46 - everything works fine even `RBT` rules however, when 47 is then inserted data is lost and only 50,40,25,45 and 75 appear.

```
//Left Rotate
        public void LeftRotate(BNode root, BNode x)//violatingNode)
        {

                BNode y = x.right;
                x.right = y.left;
                if (y.left != null)
                    y.left.parent = x;
                if (x.parent == null)
                    root = y;
                else if (x.parent.left == x)
                    x.parent.left = y;
                else
                    x.parent.right = y;
                y.left = x;
                y.parent = x.parent;
                x.parent = y;
        }

//Right Rotate
        public void RightRotate(BNode root, BNode x) //BNode violatingNode
        {
            BNode y = x.left;
            x.left = y.right;
            if (y.right != null)
            {
                y.right.parent = x;
            }
            if (x.parent == null)
            {
                root = y;
            }
            else if (x.parent.left == x)
            {
                x.parent.left = y;
            }
            else
                x.parent.right = y;

            y.right = x;
            y.parent = x.parent;
            x.parent = y;
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure about how red black trees work. Never had to look in to it. I would guess that it's your replacement of root that's the issue. You're just updating the local variable root which will do nothing. You will need to either return the root so that the caller can update the root, or have a parameter which you can mutate the root in (eg. a Tree object). Alternatively, if this is C# (which is one of your two confusing language tags), you can make root a ref parameter so that you can modify it, I would probably not recommend that as an option.

Comment: If BNode is a struct, change it to class or use ref.